# Most performance optimal foreach function with getting index

Tags: javascript, foreach

What is the most performance effective `foreach` loop in JS with returning index?

best loading times have:
but how can I get `index` of each loop?

```
spacecrafts.forEach(function(spacecraft) {
  // how can i call index without calling prototype and only with anonymous function? 
  console.log(index,spacecraft);
});
```

Comment: The second parameter of the callback is the index. You can write `function(spacecraft, index) {...}`.

Comment: `forEach` is hardly "performance effective". But why do you need "optimal performance" at all?

Comment: I'd stick with the oldschool `for(var i = 0, len = spacecrafts.length(); i < len; i++) { }` we all know and love.

Comment: @PauloAvelar It seems to be for a videogame and I think the array become sparce very quickly so the classic `for` will fail quickly and would require a check on the value on every loop.

Comment: Right, foreach id two times faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like ShanShan said in the comment, the index is the second parameter of the anonymous function being passed to forEach. The code would look like this.

```
spacecrafts.forEach(function(spacecraft, index) { 
  console.log(index,spacecraft);
});
```

If for some reason you really need performance, go ahead and use [BenchmarkJs](http://benchmarkjs.com/) to test your particular use cases and find what is fastest.  In general, the built-in Array prototype functions aren't as performant as a basic for-loop.  You might want to look into using a library like lodash, or underscore which say they try and be performant.